# Android - determine number of fingers touching

Tags: android

How do you determine the number of fingers are touching the screen at the same time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get through your `MotionEvent` of in `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`

```
int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
```

[**MotionEvent.getPointerCount()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount%28%29) returns the number of active pointers